# Cast EventHandler into MouseEventHandler in .Net C++?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++, casting, event-handling

I have some problems trying to convert an EventHandler to a MouseEventHandler.

```
System::EventHandler^ method = gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MainForm::Exit_Action);
if (e->trigger == "onmousedown") {
     c->MouseDown += (MouseEventHandler^)(method); // error
```

(this refer to a System::Windows::Forms::Form class)

Is there a method to do the trick ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `EventHandler` is not a `MouseEventHandler` (they are even not in the same inheritance hierarchy), so this shouldn't work.

Why not create a new (well, *gcnew*) `MouseEventHandler` inside `if`? It's cheap :)

(In C# you usually create an implicit lambda by using something like `c.MouseDown += Exit_Action;` but I don't know if there's a syntax like that in C++/CLI.)

Comment: Hum ...
The handler "method" is not alwais linked to the same function, so i can't create the MouseEventHandler inside if.
I just need to retrieve the pointer from my EventHandler ...

Comment: @cyrbil: well, although extracting the method is possible (with reflection), why again not store `Exit_Action` or other method into a variable?

Comment: How could i do this ? I tried with IntPtr but had failed.
Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure about the syntax in C++. In C# it would be something like `Func<object, MouseEventArgs>`. In C++/CLI perhaps `Func<Object^, MouseEventArgs^>^`?

Comment: I have an [error C2843](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9490z27z(v=vs.71).aspx) with `void (MainForm::*funcPtr)(Object^, EventArgs^);`. 
Do you know how it should be writted, i fail with all my attempts ? -_-
 It's damn more simple in C# for sure ;)

Comment: @cyrbil: maybe `System::Action<Object^, EventArgs^>^ funcPtr` instead?

Comment: nop, i finally solve the problems with a bunch of conditions. It's pretty ugly but working.